# Very slow convergence with CNN

Tags: cnn, object-detection, convergence

I am new to deep learning. I am working on training an SSD model on a set of small objects. I am using Adam gradient descent for optimization and a large input (800x800), but I seem to only get an improvement of 0.010 after every 20 or so epochs(350 steps).

What can I do or look for to speed up convergence on this model?

Comment: please put your architecture. Your input is very large, you may end up with very large dense layers after convolutional layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the below mentioned techniques and check

1. Add Batch Normalization
2. Increase the learning rate
3. Standard/Normalize the inputs if you have not done it already